# convert NPRG9x07.mbn to NPRG9x07.bin

Tags: unpacking, binary-format

Hello i have qualcomm based bootloader for mdm9x07 platform i want to convert to bin format but i did not find any script that does the conversion 
here are the mbn files : [NPRG9x07.mbn](http://51.15.188.30/mw40/NPRG9x07.mbn)[2](http://51.15.188.30/mw40/ENPRG9x07.mbn)

[ENPRG9x07.mbn](http://51.15.188.30/mw40/ENPRG9x07.mbn)

Comment: What do you mean to bin file? It is a binary file already.

Comment: it is mbn file which contains library so i need to patch the bootloader which must be in .bin format to be able to interact with flash memory like dumping flash memory writing etc ...

Answer (score 1):

The `NPRG9x07.mbn` and `ENPRG9x07.mbn` files are both regular [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) files, which should be recognized without problem by most disassemblers and decompilers.

The `NPRG9x07.mbn` file is used for regular flashing, and loads at 0x80000000, while the `ENPRG9x07.mbn` file is used as the emergency downloader, and loads at 0x08000000.

Both are uploaded to the device using the sahara protocol, where the upload of `ENPRG9x07.mbn` is handled by the bootrom, while `NPRG9x07.mbn` is handled by the regular bootloader: `sbl1.mbn`.

Both implement the same download protocol, the one which starts with the flashingtool sending `"QCOM fast download protocol host"` and the device responding with `"QCOM fast download protocol targ"`.